# Re-registering an AnnotationView

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

`A` and `B` are different kinds of `MKMarkerAnnotationView` classes. In my MapViewController I register `A` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self

    mapView.register(A.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    for annotation in annotations {
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

I have a `UISwitch` that I want to use to change the registered AnnotationView from `A` to `B`.

```
@IBAction func didToggleSwitch(_ sender: Any) {

    mapView.register(B.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    // remove all annotations
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

    //populate all annotations
    for annotation in annotations {
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

}
```

The registered view isn't being updated. Any ideas why?

Edit: I've noticed that when I zoom out and pan the map around, some annotations update to the new AnnotationView, and some don't. I suspect this is due to using a `reuseIdentifier`. How do I get all annotations to conform to the new AnnotationView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I created a boolean within my `MKAnnotation` class and configured the annotation properties within annotationView `A` based on that boolean. When I hit the `UISwitch`, I loop through all my annotation objects, toggle their boolean's value, and re-register the annotationView, and load them up.